# flutter getx rxlist in obx error show widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

hi i am using getx on my project . I have RxList and i use Obx for shows my data :

```
RxList dasteBandi = [].obs;



void changeTodasteBandi(int index) {
dasteBandi.removeAt(index);
```

}

and widget is :

```
Obx(
  () => ListView.builder(
    // itemCount: catList.length,
    itemCount: taskController.dasteBandi.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: themeController.isDark.value == true
                ? Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3)
                : Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1.h),
        child: ListTile(
          // title: Text(catList[index]),
          title: Text(taskController.dasteBandi[index]),

          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print(index);
              // setState(() {
              //   catList.removeAt(index);
              // });
              taskController.changeTodasteBandi(index);
            },
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.remove_circle_sharp,
              color: MyUtils.kRedColor,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

when i use this widget i have this error :

### Exception caught by widgets library
Stack Overflow
The relevant error-causing widget was
GetMaterialApp

Stack Overflow
The relevant error-causing widget was
Obx

when i am remove this line
itemCount: taskController.dasteBandi.length,
and changed it with:
itemCount: catList.length,

and use setState() every thing is fine but when i use getx controller for list i have that error

Comment: Could you clean up the error and let us know what line in your code is specifically throwing the error?  Line 38 is not specific enough.  It might also help to use Dart pad to reproduce the error.

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Comment: Hey, do you know how to solve this problem because i have the same issue